# Unable to run pySpark job on the Dataproc

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I try to run pySpark job on the new Dataproc cluster created using:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
 --region=${REGION} \
 --image-version=1.4 \
 --master-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
 --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
 --bucket=${BUCKET_NAME} \
 --optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
 --enable-component-gateway
```

then I try to run different jobs, all that create spark context result in infinite loop:

```
 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

example script:

```
import pyspark

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
rdd = sc.parallelize(['Hello,', 'world!', 'dog', 'elephant', 'panther'])
words = sorted(rdd.collect())
print(words)
```

added to the cluster using

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark pyspark_sort.py \
    --cluster=${BUCKET_NAME} \
    --region=us-central1
```

When I run something like that:

```
import getpass
import sys
import imp

print('This job is running as "{}".'.format(getpass.getuser()))
print(sys.executable, sys.version_info)
for package in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(imp.find_module(package))
```

I get a successful output:

```
Job [f10a70ab95c54c8a9fa471429b91153b] submitted.
Waiting for job output...
This job is running as "root".
/opt/conda/default/bin/python sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
(None, '/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas', ('', '', 5))
(None, '/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy', ('', '', 5))
Job [f10a70ab95c54c8a9fa471429b91153b] finished successfully.
```

Thank's in advance!

Comment: When trying to create a cluster based on the first command and submitting your `pyspark_sort.py` it had worked as expected. Have you noticed the typo `--cluster=${BUCKET_NAME}` in the `jobs submit` ?

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz same here. For some reason after some time working on JupyterLab and/or running jobs, cluster stops responding. I'm not sure how I can search for the dead processes to clear them. Currently, the only fix is to recreate the cluster. Thank you!